# Seleccionar todos los checkbox de una sola sección

Tags: javascript, mysql, html5, php7

Estoy realizando una página que permite a un grupo de personas puedan pedir unas fichas con información de productos. Para esto, quiero hacer un modo de "añadir al carrito".

Hay un `<input type="checkbox">` y un `<details>` que me servirá como el "seleccionar todo" de la información dentro del `<details>`

Aquí está el código:

```
//Primero buscamos todos los input que esten dentro de summay y que sean de primer nivel
var chck_padre = document.querySelectorAll("summary>input");
//Si chck_padre existe y no esta null,  entonces entramos
if(chck_padre != undefined && chck_padre != null)
  {
  //Ahora recorremos el arreglo de los padres
  chck_padre.forEach(function (elemento){
    //Asignamos un elemento click a cada elemento checkbox padre
    elemento.onclick = function (){
    ///Ahora siendo una base tu input padre, entonces subimos dos niveles para encontrar a details y apartir de details buscar los elementos hijos checkbox
    var details = elemento.parentElement.parentElement;
    //ahora buscamos los chckbox hijos que estan dentro de deatils
    var chckbox = details.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox'][name^='check']");
    //Recorremos estos checkbox hijos
    chckbox.forEach(function (chck_hijo){
        //Verificamos si nuestro elemento padre llamado: elemento esta checked true ó false y le deamos el mismo estado; true o false.
        elemento.checked ? (chck_hijo.checked = true) : (chck_hijo.checked = false);
    }); //Fin chckbox forEach
  } //Fin onclick function 
}); // Fin chck_padre forEach
}

<!-- language: lang-html -->

<section id="muestreo">
    <?php
    //Aquí se consulta el programa que será el primer <details>
    $programas=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM programas");
    while ($prog=mysqli_fetch_array($programas)) {
        //Aquí inicia el primer <details>, que será el que se muestre como principal.
        echo "<details class='programa'>";
        //El título, serán todos los programas registrados.
        echo "<summary>";
        echo $prog['nombre_prog'];
        //Este $id es para delimitar aún más los productos.
        $id=$prog['id_prog'];
        echo "</summary>";
        //Aquí se consultan las categorías que pertenecen al programa de arriba.
        $productos=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM productos GROUP BY sub_categoria_prod WHERE id_prog='$id'");
        while($prod=mysqli_fetch_array($productos)){
            //Este es el segundo <details> que se mostrará al hacer click en el nombre del programa consultado arriba.
            echo "<details class='hijo'>";
            //El título aquí, será la sub_categoría a la que pertenecen varios productos.
            echo "<summary>";
            //Este input será el "seleccionar todo".
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check1'>";
            echo $prod['sub_categoria_prod'];
            echo "</summary>";
            //Aquí se define la sub-categoría para delimitar la infomación y dividirlos en grupos.
            $categoria=$prod['sub_categoria_prod'];
            //El $id se repite para delimitar la información a mostrar.
            $id=$prog['id_prog'];
            //Aquí se consulta la información de las fichas que pertenecen a la sub-categoría mostrada.
            $informacion=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE sub_categoria_prod='$categoria' AND id_prog='$id'");
            while ($i=mysqli_fetch_array($informacion)) {
                //Este input es para poder elegir la ficha exacta que se necesita pedir.
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check1' class='id' value='" . $i['cod_prod'] . "'>";
                echo "<table border='1'class='tabla'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Nombre del producto (SIBOL).</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'><strong>" . $i['sibol_prod'] . "</strong></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Nombre comercial del producto.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['nombre_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Calidad.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['calidad_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Generalidades.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['generalidades_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Requisitos generales.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['re_generales_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Requisitos espec&iacute;ficos.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['re_espe_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Empaque y rotulado.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['empaque_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Presentaci&oacute;n.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['presentacion_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Imagen de referencia.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'><img src='" . $i['imagen_prod'] . "' id='referencia'></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
            }
            //Termina el <details> de las sub categorías.
            echo "</details>";
        }
        //Termina el <details> de los programas.
        echo "</details>";
    }
    ?>
</section>
```

Sé que es extenso, pero ya no sé qué más hacer. Por favor, necesito que al seleccionar el input que está en la clase "hijos" me seleccione las fichas que **pertenecen sólo a la sub-categoría que fue seleccionada en el checkbox**.

Comment: ¿Valdría una respuesta usando [JQuery](https://jquery.com/)?

Comment: En este punto, cualquier cosa me sirve. Jajajajaja. Es lo único que me falta para entregarlo.

Comment: te sugiero que primero cargues la parte html/php y en la parte inferior venga o agregues tu codigo javascript

Answer (score 0):

Solo cambia el orden, primero que se ejecute el PHP y posteriormente que se ejecute el Javascript, además agrega esto en tu Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() { //Se ejecutara el Javascript hasta que la página se cargue por completo
   //Pega aquí todo el código Javascript
};
```